# CopyFromScreen Copy not correct location only on Touchdisplays

Tags: c#

In my c# i use CopyFromScreen
On many pc's the script ar always ok,
the panel1 in my Form will be saved as image
but when i use touchdisplays in the image is evrything but newer the panel1
i can not understand why?

```
        private void buttonInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image bmp = new Bitmap(panel1.Width, panel1.Height);
        
        var gg = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
        var rect = panel1.RectangleToScreen(panel1.ClientRectangle);
        
        gg.CopyFromScreen(rect.Location, Point.Empty, panel1.Size);
        bmp.Save(@"C:\Temp\test.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);          
       
        Graphics g = panel1.CreateGraphics();
        g.Clear(Color.WhiteSmoke);
    }
```

thx for your help

Answer (score 0):

I found it out, the problem was the windows scaling. When i set it on 100% the Problem solved.
thx a lot